# How to Check param from iReport with database?

Tags: jasper-reports

Currently I'm doing report using iReport 3.0.0

I have this one field which is `Indicator` (A, B and C).

I group by this field so that All records will print in different page based on `Indicator`. (I use iReport `Group By` function)

However, I have certain time that when it query my sql, it will return only A and C.. How if I wanna generate `Ind = B` too with text **NO RECORD FOUND**

This is my current expression:

```
($F{IND}.equals("A")) ? "SMS MESSAGE NOT FOUND" :  ( 
   ($F{IND}.equals("B")) ? "CW MESSAGE NOT FOUND" : (
    ($F{IND}.equals("C")) ? "STATUS MIS-MATCHED" : null
   )
 )
```

How can I check if `IND = B` not exist in my database, then print **NO RECORD FOUND** ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special variable to count the rows in the group B.

Either use the built-in variable `${YOUGROUP_COUNT}` ([source](https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/533199/counter-rows-group))

Or increment a variable yourself : see more information [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-group-count-variable-calculation-jasper-reports)

When you have this variable set up, you can have a `textField` containing **NO RECORD FOUND**. Use the attribute `printWhenExpression` to display this textField only when the group count is equal to zero.

```
<staticText>
    <reportElement x="234" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="05895bf2-3ce1-4d88-82fe-ff3fd650eaf6">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[${YOURGROUP_COUNT} == 0]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <text><![CDATA[NO RECORD FOUND]]></text>
</staticText>
```

Don't display this static text element in a detail band, because it won't be displayed if there is no record. Use any other band to display it.